# I can't access the system: Error: "unknown filesystem. grub rescue"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

i'm a fresh ubuntu user and I've installed a double boot with Wind 8 and Ubuntu 13.04, but since yesterday I'm receiving an error showing:

> error: unknown filesystem
>   grub rescue>

The fact is when I do ls (hdX,gptY)/ all I get is "error:unknown filesystem" again.

And the solutions posted don't work because I don't know why but I can't access the BIOS pressin F2 or to the boot pressing F12, the simply don't work since the error.

Comment: What solutions had been posted? Does the screen with the brand of your PC appear? If no, try pressing F12/F2 while switching on.

Comment: I tried making a live USB but as I don't have access to the BIOS I'm not able to boot it. The brand apppears but it doesn't matter when I press F2/F12, nothing happens. It used to work but not now.

Answer (score 0):

Get a live USB memory stick/CD etc. with Ubuntu and chroot into your system (more on that here: superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation). Then in the terminal which is chrooted into your system, type `update-grub`. Then close the terminal and re-boot to your hopefully-working GRUB!

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I don't know how to enter the BIOS setup and thus I can't boot a USB/CD

Comment: What does your computer show for literally one or two seconds before anything else? Is there the manufacturer's logo? That's the time to press a function key. Also does your keyboard have a function lock (like num lock)?